# How do I integrate StyleCop 4.7 with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop

I really want to use StyleCop with my Visual Studio 2013, but unfortunately it won't work. I've installed the 4.7 version from the [official site](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), checking all options, both VS Studio integration and MSBuild integration, following the precise instructions (download, install while VS applications are closed, then start VS) but it just won't show up in my Visual Studio 2013.

The StyleCop website says that it should be compatible with VS2013. It won't show up anything related to StyleCop under tools and it won't show up the 'Run StyleCop' action when I right-click my C# project. Already tried the repair option from the installation menu and even re-installed it. Haven't made any progress.

Can someone please help me with this? Maybe one has had experience with this before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using (Express, Professional, etc.)?

Comment: Good point, I'm currently using the Professional edition.

Comment: As an alternative, you could install the StyleCop.MSBuild NuGet package into your projects so that the referenece to StyleCop travels with your source code and analysis runs on every build everywhere. This removes the need to install StyleCop on every machine you use, including build servers.

Comment: You mean as some kind of library instead of the integration with VS2013? That sounds like a good idea if the integration things really doesn't work out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open Visual studio
Open Package Manager Console from TOOLS > LIBRARY PACKAGE MANAGER menu

Run the following command

```
install-package stylecop.msbuild
```

The above command will download the latest stable required dlls and files and integrate style cop with your project. Build your project and any stylecop errors will be shown in the warnings section.

If you don't find the package manager for some reason in the above menu, please refer this link for instructions on how to install http://surajdeshpande.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio/

If you want your build to succeed only if all stylecop errors are fixed, you will need to make some changes to the project file to set a boolean to not treat stylecop errors as warnings.

Open the .csproj file for your project in notepad, and find the first PropertyGroup section within the file. Add a new tag to set the StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings flag to false. For example:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{4B4DB6AA-A021-4F95-92B7-B88B5B360228}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TestProject</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TestProject</AssemblyName>
    <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

A sample proj file content with `<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>` is shown above.

The build will be successful only after all sylecop errors are fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers seems to be deprecated in 2015..

For VS Community 2013 Update 5:

1) Install "JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2 [En]"

2) Go to Resharper-> Extensions:

[image]

3) Install Resharper.Stylecop from there

[image]

**Update:** Ok, for ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2 + **StyleCop by JetBrains 4.8**
I get this error: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206009179-StyleCop-integration-with-ReSharper-10-x-VS2015- 
But there is recommendation to ignore this error. Seems to work after restart VS

(I also have [reSP](http://subpointsolutions.com/resp/) installed, for Sharepoint code analysis)

Comment: Please use the "StyleCop by JetBrains" extension instead of this "ReSharper.StyleCop". It fixes a number of crashes, memory leaks and performance issues, and doesn't require the StyleCop Visual Studio addin to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated the stylecops 4.7 with Visual Studio 2013 (Web) using following steps.

1. In order to integrate StyleCop with a project, an `<Import>` needs to be added to the .csproj file (versions and paths might differ):

If you used the official installer and installed the 'MSBuild integration' component, your `<Import>` will look like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> 
<!-- Your StyleCop <Import> will go here -->
<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />
```

Note: You need to add the above line in each and every project in your solution.

1. Copy `Settings.StyleCop` in the project solution folder from C:\Program Files\StyleCop 4.7 on solution root folder or add as a solution item.
2. Double click the `Settings.StyleCop` file as configure the rules. You should be able to use the stylecops in your project.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to format your answer to make it more readable. Please recheck it to make sure it is correct.