# StyleCop not integrated with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, stylecop

I have problem with integration the newest version StyleCop with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I have also installed Re# 9.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639815/how-do-i-integrate-stylecop-4-7-with-visual-studio-2013) not working on my pc :/

I have installed StyleCop nuget packages.
[image]

I changed entry "True" in csproj file (by notepad). It works I get many error from StyleCop.

1) Why StyleCop is not integrated with Visual Studio? I should see "Run StyleCop" option in context menu on project, I do not see.
2) How can I determine path for my setting file in csproj?

Comment: In your screenshot it lists stylecop as an installed package. Setting that property to true in csproj will stop your project from building if stylecop finds warnings in your code.

Comment: Yes, it works. My purpose is to have StypeCop integrated with Visual Studio to can manage rules in easy way.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question now. I thought you were saying stylecop is not working

Comment: I have this set up at work. I will have a look tomorrow and let you know how it is in my Visual Studio

Comment: Great, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

The [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/) `StyleCop.MSBuild` simplifies the adding of the properties to a csproj required to run StyleCop as part of the build. It also references a StyleCop instance inside `/packages/` which means that it is downloaded from sourcecontrol and each developer does not need StyleCop installed.

R# by itself doesn't have any StyleCop settings, however it's ruleset can be configured to match StyleCop's. The easiest way to do this is with a [plugin](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.StyleCop/). This is currently in prerelease for R# 9.1 so make sure you have `Include prelease plugins` checked inside `R# Settings > Environment > Extension Manager`.

To get the context menus, you need to install [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) on your local machine. This currently does not support Visual Studio 2015.

It is important to keep the version used by R#, the version used by StyleCop.MsBuild and the version installed on your machine insync otherwise it will lead to false positives.

Comment: For context menus in VS2015, now you can try Visual-StyleCop. This extension is based from original source code from codeplex, I updated it to work with VS2015 and most common C# 6 specifications. To install it, start VS2015, go to Tools \ Extensions and update, and search for stylecop. More information on how to install it here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313249/stylecop-integration-with-visual-studio-2015-rc/32362690#32362690](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313249/stylecop-integration-with-visual-studio-2015-rc/32362690#32362690)

Comment: Is there any way to run style cop with out installation (Like copying the dlls for StyleCop build) for creating custom rules? I need to run a simple custome rule. But my organization policy wont accept installations.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 'Run StyleCop' options in the Tools menu and the context menu of the Solution Explorer. I have ReSharper installed, but I don't think it is ReSharper that adds these menu items. VS Express edition does not support integration of add-ins if you are using an Express/Community edition..

[image: Context Menu]

[image: Tools Menu]

Comment: Your screen show situation which I want to reach. I don't see this options. I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Do you install something more than this three nuget packages, which I have?

Comment: I can't find any reason why you would not have the menu items. I'm guessing you have already tried uninstall and reinstall?